# Backup IoT core image

Tags: c#, iot, windows-10-iot-core

I know that I can backup Raspbian image using Win32 Disk imager, but seems Win32 Disk imager is not working for Windows IoT core, is there any better way to backup installed image file of Windows IoT core ?

Comment: This help you out? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/iot/2015/12/14/windows-10-iot-core-image-creation/

Comment: thanks @ Pedro G. Dias

Answer (score 1):

I think the tool you need here is Windows Imaging and Configuration Designer.

Main article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn916113(v=vs.85).aspx

Getting started: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn916112(v=vs.85).aspx

With this you can create a base image that can be reused. It might not do exactly what you need when creating a backup of something you've already created, but it will allow you to customise a new image from scratch.

Here's the download for the Windows Assessment and Deployment Kit which includes ICD: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/windows-assessment-deployment-kit

Note; you'll need local admin rights to do most of this. Just in case you aren't already.

Hope this helps.